# MySQL : Find Count of Column joined from sum of different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

table a

```
+----------+------------+------------+
|session_id| product_id | orders     |
+----------+------------+------------+
| 1        | 11         | 0          |
| 1        | 22         | 2          |
| 1        | 34         | 1          |
| 2        | 11         | 0          |
| 3        | 43         | 0          |
| 3        | 11         | 1          |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

table b:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|product_id |category_id   |
+-----------+--------------+
| 11        |    100       |
| 12        |    101       |
| 34        |    102       |
| 22        |    103       |
| 43        |    104       |
| 13        |    105       |
+-----------+--------------+
```

What I want is a table which consists of how many `category_id` were there in each `session_id` and also total orders placed in that `session_id`

```
+-----------+--------------------+--------+
|session_id | count(category_id) | orders |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+
| 1         | 3                  | 3      |
| 2         | 1                  | 0      |
| 3         | 2                  | 1      |
+-----------+--------------------+--------+
```

I tried:

```
select a.session_id,count(b.category_id),sum(a.orders) from a
join table b
on a.product_id = b.product id
```

is this query right?

Please help me. I am a beginner

Comment: Did you tried anything so far!

Comment: @ubaidashraf sir, i am a beginner in this, i was thinking to do a join between two tables where a.product_id = b. product id

Comment: @ubaidashraf sir, please take a look, i have edited my question, with code

Comment: Have you read [group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    I tried with 2 methods    
    1)...SELECT a.session_id,COUNT(b.category_id),SUM(a.orders) FROM #a a
        LEFT JOIN  #b b
        ON a.product_id = b.product_id GROUP BY a.session_id
GROUP BY a.Session_ID

      2...)  SELECT D.SESSION_ID,COUNT(CATEGORY_ID),SUM(D.ORDERS) FROM #A D

        OUTER APPLY 
           ( 
           SELECT CATEGORY_ID,PRODUCT_ID FROM #B B 
           WHERE D.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID
           ) A 
           GROUP BY D.SESSION_ID 
        GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you have t join tha tables, then group with the field you want.

```
SELECT a.Session_ID, Count(Category_ID) CategoryCount, SUM(Orders) NumberOfOrders
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.Product_ID = b. Product ID
GROUP BY a.Session_ID
```

Personally, and since I don't have any info on the data structure I prefered using the LEft outer join since in case the product_id had no category, then no results of this product will show.

(unless each product should have a category, or the user needs only the products that has a category, you have to use the `INNER JOIN`)

Comment: Why did you use LEFT OUTER JOIN? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Just use left join for showing all result from table A
by using only join its show the result exist in both table only.

```
SELECT a.session_id,COUNT(b.category_id),SUM(a.orders) FROM a
LEFT JOIN  b 
ON a.product_id = b.product_id GROUP BY a.`session_id`
```

Comment: you missed the group by!! This will result in an error